# What counts as low health for Killing Blow?

Tags: borderlands-2

Zero has a skill in the Bloodshed tree that

> Massively increases Melee Damage against enemies with low health.

What exactly counts as low health in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I initially guessed `50%` health was considered "low health."  If you were to melee attack light enemies (i.e., non-heavy enemies like most **Bullymongs**) at `50%`, it would cause them to stagger.  Though after experimenting, this doesn't seem to be the case.

***Based on my observations*, I'd say "low health" is ~33% health (or 1/3 health).**

Fortunately, it is pretty clear when the ability was applied in a kill.  Normally you deal a fixed amount of damage to everyone.  When the ability is applied, you see a boost in the damage dealt and you get a nice "buzz" sound and a slashing animation for every hit.

---

To test this, I respec'ed Zero and went off to fight making sure I didn't level up any more during the tests.  As a baseline, I fought off enemies with only the **Deception** skill and **no other skills**.  Every melee attack I dealt gave `55` damage.

I saved and restarted to go on another run.  This time I added **Killing Blow Level 1** to the mix.  Again, most hits dealt `55` damage.  Using a weak gun, I chipped enemies' health to around `50%` (as close as I can get it) and hit them with a melee attacks.  Still did `55` damage.  I then tried for `25%`.  Again, as best as I can, I chipped them down to as close as I can to `25%` then hit them with a melee attack.  I got boosted damage and other indicators of a successful hit.  So it's definitely applied at least at `25%`.

However I noticed that at times when I wasn't quite at `25%` but a little higher, I was still able to get the successful hit.  So *apparently it was higher*.  After a few more tests, **I came to the conclusion that it is at `33%` at max.**

To see if the level of the skill affects this, I tried again with **Killing Blow Level 2** and up.  You get even more damage of course but it still seemed to apply at `33%` and didn't change.

Comment: Good work...that's odd though because other skills like Siren's Reaper activate at 50% health

Answer (score 1):

[User Zikel, in the /r/Borderlands subreddit tested Killing Blow](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/15op84/many_skill_descriptions_are_misleading_dont_tell/) and came up with the ff. results:

> #### When exactly is an enemy "*low on health*" ?
>
> When below **30% health**.
>
> The damage bonus from this skill is multiplicative rather than
> additive, that is why you get astronomical numbers when using it.

---

<sup>Source: [Reddit /r/Borderlands post by user Zikel, "*Many skill descriptions are misleading, don't tell the full story or straight up lie to you. I took it upon my self to test EVERYTHING and clear up the confusion. Here are the results.*"](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/15op84/many_skill_descriptions_are_misleading_dont_tell/)</sup>